# How to enter command line arguments in python notepad++?

Tags: python-2.7, notepad++, command-line-arguments

I am practicing beginner's Python in Notepad++ and I am stuck when trying to give command line arguments during runtime. When I run the code, I get `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`, and I can't give input arguments. I tried using Python plugins `PyNPP`, `NppExec` and even tried running it through Notepad++'s inbuilt console but I'm still unable to give input. There is no syntactical error in the code:

```py
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv
print "the script is called : ", script
print "your first variable is : ", first
print "your second variable is :", second
print "your third variable is: ", third
```

Please explain how I can give arguments during runtime. I have searched in Google for possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

argv is a list of arguments to the python script. It should not be defined inside a script. An example:

python script.py first second third

In this case

```
sys.argv[0] is script.py
sys.argv[1] is first
sys.argv[2] is second
sys.argv[3] is third
```

Comment: I understood that but when we run code in Notepad++, it directly displays output on terminal. So, that is what I am asking where in Notepad++ can I enter this command ---> python script.py input1 input2 input3 ?

Comment: I looked up pyNPP documentaion and looks like following are the instructionsPyNPP - The PyNPP plugin gives you three additional keybinds to run python scripts:
ctrl-alt-F5 = Run script in Python
alt-shift-F5 = Run script in Python Interactive

Comment: The valuError is coming from this line `script, first, second, third = argv`